# Jersey client dependencies

Tags: java, classpath, jersey

According to [documentation](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#chapter_deps), all I need for Jersey client is `jersey-bundle.jar`. But simple code, that build request and sent it throws exception.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers
```

After adding `jsr311-api-1.0.jar` to classpath. I've got another exception.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/Response$StatusType
```

Where I can find full dependencies list for Jersey. What jars should be included. Btw I can't user Maven, Ivy, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try searching mvnrepository.com

Lookup the package you are looking for, select a version and it shows you everything the artifact depends on.

For jersey-bundle: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.13-b01

Comment: Not an answer to my question, but accept it. Short answer, I should use - jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar instead of jsr311-api-1.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

For me this meant "you're using jersey-client 1.19 but then manually calling out jsr311-api-1.0" (apparently that jersey client version [1.19] actually needs/wanted jsr311-api-1.1 instead).

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to add **bundle** for Jersey client  from [MavenLink](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.13-b01) select jar/pom from files row instead of adding independent/separate jar files. if you do so by adding individual jar you will  get another/different error. Better way is to add bundle (group of dependent jar for Jersy client).